# How to calculate angle from 2D projection

Tags: geometry

[I have picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQoJm.png) of interior wall. I know that angles A and B are 90deg in reality and I need to calculate angle C.

A in picture is 95 deg
B 123 deg
C 142 deg

Comment: Angle C could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot find the real angle C from just the projection angles. The only thing you can know from the picture is that the angle C isn't larger than 142°.